# bootstrap typeahead getting results data-source results to appear?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

i am not getting any results when i search.

```
<input type="text" class="span1" id="tag_field" data-items='4' data-provide="typeahead" data-source='[<?php echo json_encode($groups); ?>]' >
<?php echo json_encode($groups); ?>
```

when i echo out json_encond($groups) it appears in this format

```
{"35":"biology","37":"economist","33":"programmers"}
```

if i type in the data source using this format i do get results.

```
 data-source='["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona"]'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Typeahead plugin is expecting an Array of Strings as the `data-source`. Your `json_encode` is creating an Object and you're just wrapping it in an array when you echo it.

You want something like this:

```
<?php
$groups = array("biology", "economist", "programmers");
?>

<input type="text" class="span1" id="tag_field" data-items='4' data-provide="typeahead" data-source='<?php echo json_encode($groups); ?>'>
```

You can use the [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function in PHP to ensure your `$groups` is a basic numerically indexed array.